# How to configure postfix to pipe all incoming email to a script?

Tags: postfix, scripting

Using postfix, I'd like all incoming mail, to any address (including those that don't map to local users) to be piped to a script.  I've tried configuring `mailbox_command` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
mailbox_command = /path/to/myscript.py
```

This works great if the user is a local user, but it fails for "unknown" users who don't have aliases.  I tried setting `luser_relay` to a local user, but this pre-empts `mailbox_command`, and so the command doesn't get run.  I tried setting `local_recipient_maps=` (empty string), but the message is still bounced (unknown user).

Is there a magic invocation I can use to get all known and unknown users to go to the script as well?

Full `/etc/postfix/main.cf` follows -- it's the default Ubuntu 10.04, with the exception of the `mailbox_command` line:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ... snip ...
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = sassafras, ... snip ...,localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

mailbox_command = /path/to/my/script.py
```

Comment: After the script, what then? This sounds like the kind of thing that virus scanners and spam filters do, maybe you can find a guide to configuring one of those and use its configuration for your script?

Comment: The messages go to a web application.  So after the script: a database, other processing, other stuff, but not normal mail stuff.  The key question is getting the unknown users to not bounce -- this is outside the normal virus/spam scenario, where you would bounce unmapped users.

Comment: @user67641 hi do i need to inject the mail into postfix in my script or by adding some more lines in master.cf

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok, I just got this working -- though hairier than I thought it would be.  I dropped the `maildir_command` part, and went with `transport_maps`.  The key is to do 5 things:

1. Set up a db file to handle aliases (and add a catch-all alias)
2. Set up a db file to map the 'transport' for the domain in question to a special handler.
3. Compile the db files into berkeley db format that postfix wants.
4. Set up the handler in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` to pipe mail to the script.
5. Set `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to use the transport db for `transport_maps`, and the alias db for `virtual_alias-maps`.

(1) Create `/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases` to add a catch-all alias -- `localuser` needs to be an existing local user:

```
@mydomain.tld   localuser@mydomain.tld
```

(2) Create `/etc/postfix/transport` to add a transport mapping.  "mytransportname" can be whatever you want; it's used below in `master.cf`:

```
mydomain.tld    mytransportname:
```

(3) Next, both `transport` and `virtual_aliases` need to be compiled into berkeley db files:

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

(4) Add the transport to `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
mytransportname   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=localuser argv=/path/to/my/script.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

(5) In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
  ...
  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
  virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

And... good to go!  Sheesh.

Comment: extremely useful answer

Comment: Virtual alias maps are not needed.  You can accomplish the same thing with `relay_domains` (in which case the transport file can filter based on the actual To: address).

Comment: I found you can route all virtual mail to a script with `virtual_transport = mailcaptcha:` in `main.cf` and `mailcaptcha unix -       n       n       -       -       pipe 
  flags=FR user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/perl /usr/local/mail-captcha/verify.pl ${sender} ${recipient}` in `master.cf`. See http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html and http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html.

Comment: The (4) should be in one single line, is that right? Also doesn't it require a `postfix restart` or `reload` or something like this? Last thing: is there a log file to see the mails who arrived to postfix?

Comment: @Basj, the log file is `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: In order to use the envelope recipient ( `RCTP TO`) in the script, either append the envelope recipient as header by using `flags=FRDO`, or pass it to the script as parameter by adding the `${original_recipient}` command-line macro. Documentation: http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html

Answer (score 5):

The only time I've used something like this was for a specific user's mailbox. All that was required was to alias that user's name to a pipe and a process in aliases:

> pong: "| /usr/local/bin/gotit.pl"

This sent traffic destined for "pong@mymailserver.com" to a perl script I wrote to process it.

gotit.pl (as an example, don't pick on me for crappy programming skillz =). It's job was to process an email I'd sent to our Exchange server (where it was auto-replied via some VB code) to verify that Exchange was processing email in a timely fashion. If not, the mail server would send out an alert email to our pagers and write a lock file so we didn't get constantly spammed.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use vars qw ( $mung $sent $tvalue $remainder $delta $fout );
$mung = time;
while (<STDIN>) {
    ($sent, $tvalue, $remainder ) = split /: /, $_, 3;
    $tvalue =~ s/(\D+)//g;
    chomp($tvalue);
    $delta = $mung-$tvalue;
    if ( $sent =~ "Sent" ) {
        $fout = "/var/spool/mailcheck/$tvalue";
        next unless ( -e $fout );
        open (TMP, "> $fout") or die "Couldn't open output file: $!\n";
        print TMP "Received in: $delta seconds.\n";
                close TMP;
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, and just redirect @mydomain.tld to pong and all incoming main for mydomain.tld will be piped.

Comment: and for those of us using multiple virtual domains, don't forget to redirect it to pong@localhost so that it doesn't attach the default domain name to the alias

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of headaches I put together [this solution](https://www.industrialcuriosity.com/2019/08/mail-forwarding-and-piping-emails-with.html) based on a couple of different sources that resulted in much less effort, the critical steps were configuring `virtual_alias_domains` as well as `virtual_alias_maps` and making sure that the virtual mapping was to `my-alias@localhost` instead of just `my-alias`. In my example the command alias is to pipe the email to a website API endpoint, but it could just as easily pipe into something else.

Here are the steps you'll need to take:

- Set up your A and MX records for your domain, the A record @ pointing to the IP of the server you’re going to be receiving emails on and MX with the hostname @ and the value `10 mail.your-domain-name`
- `sudo apt-get install postfix`
- Select "Internet Site" and enter your-domain-name (fully qualified)
- `sudo vi /etc/postfix/main.cf`
- Add mail.your-domain-name to the list of `mydestination` values
- Append

```
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

to the end of the file

- `sudo apt-get vi /etc/aliases`

```
curl_email: "|curl --data-binary @- http://your-domain-name/email"
```

- `sudo newaliases`
- `sudo apt-get vi /etc/postfix/virtual_domains`

```
example.net   #domain
example.com   #domain
your-domain-name   #domain
```

(the #domain fields suppress warnings)

- `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_domains`
- `sudo apt-get vi /etc/postfix/virtual`

```
info@your-domain-name bob@gmail.com
everyone@your-domain-name bob@gmail.com jim@gmail.com
email_processor@your-domain-name curl_email@localhost
@your-domain-name catchall@whereveryouwant.com
ted@example.net jane@outlook.com
```

- `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
- `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload`

Answer (score 0):

I've used an old style "flat file" `Mailbox` to receive all mail (and then prune it every few hours if it's large), instead of using the modern `maildir/` folders, to process mail through scripts. You could run logrotate over the file too I suppose to keep it manageable.

This way you could simply copy all mail to a Mailbox as a local user.