# Postfix : Open relay to script

Tags: postfix, scripting

What I want to do with postfix is have an open relay that accepts all emails. I then want it to push all the received emails to a script.

I have found solutions, but they never specifiy on how to do this for an open relay or how to accept all domains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure postfix to pipe all incoming email to a script?](http://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script)

Comment: not really, since that one uses known hosts, and I want to accept all email

Comment: For this there is pcre or regex support in Postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I wrote a little blog post about that: http://blog.malowa.de/2011/04/postfix-as-spam-trap-server.html 
It is mainly about `smtp-sink`.

If you don't want that, see the dupe above.