# Piping in postfix/aliases

Tags: postfix, pipe, aliases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure postfix to pipe all incoming email to a script?](https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script)

I'm having problems setting up simple piping for Redmine (or '|cat > /tmp/temp')

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
support@myhost.com support
```

/etc/postfix/aliases:

```
support: "|/opt/redmine-1.2.2/processemail.sh"
```

main.cf

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_forwards.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = myhost.com, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailboxes.cf

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = $alias_maps
```

processemail.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/opt/redmine-1.2.2/extra/mail_handler/rdm-mailhandler.rb --url http://myhost.com --key f5obfctmGfqZWnOWNtR8 --project test --tracker support --allow-override tracker,project --verbose --unknown-user accept --no-permission-check
```

I've run `newaliases; postmap virtual; postalias aliases; postalias virtual_alias; newalias` - Yeah, probably overdoes it, but still misses the pouint :(

I've run newaliases and restarted postfix. Mail is delivered as usual, but nothing is added to /tmp

This is the only log entry saying anything about `virtual`.

```
Dec 10 04:08:41 master postfix/virtual[3112]:
A3F46AD1BF: to=<support@myhost.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.4,
delays=0.38/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
```

If I run `cat someemail | processemail.sh` in the shell, everything works. Processemail isn't even run by postfix.

Anyone knows what might be wrong? Or how I can turn on more logging?

Comment: Yes, an exact duplicate. I just found a solution and was posting it the same second the question was closed :) Would have saved a couple of hours if I found that answer first.

Answer (score 6):

Pipe Alias are implemented by [local(8)](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) postfix agent.

> relay=virtual

This means you are using the [virtual(8)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html) agent delivery to support@myhost.com but you need
[local(8)](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) to fetch that email. Maybe you using virtual as your local_transport or you need to put in your 'virtual_alias_maps' file something like:

> support@myhost.com support@localhost

This [postfix-users thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/postfix-users@postfix.org/msg14753.html) and the postfix documentation may help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple alias in `/etc/aliases` (or wherever it is located):

```
support: |/usr/local/bin/yourscripthandler
```

Don't forget to run `newaliases` afterwards.

Note that redirection (`>/tmp/blah`) is something handled by the shell, and AFAIK postfix won't invoke a shell to run your command; so `yourscripthandler` should be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/theactualscripthandler >/tmp/dummy
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I'm doing above?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry, I'll expand my answer.