# Postfix pipe to php and pass "to" email address as parameter

Tags: postfix

I setup a php piping for "incoming@mydomain.com" in my postfix configuration.

Now, what I need is to pass the "rcpt to" email address to the PHP script as a command line parameter. Is it possible?

`incoming: "|/path/to/piping.php"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. At least not in the way you do it.

You need a transport configured in `main.cf` to do it. This is a (the) solution: [How to configure postfix to pipe all incoming email to a script?](https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script)

To get the official documentation about that topic, follow the configuration with http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html and http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html